# How to use '$let' in MongoDB Aggregation Query in Scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a mongoDB aggregation query in Scala.

How do I write Scala code to use "$let" in '$project' stage?

I am wondering if [Variable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.7/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/package$$Variable$.html) should be used. Not sure how?

```
'$project': {
  'myprojitem' :{
     '$let': {
          'vars' : { 'myVariable1': { '$or': [...] } }
          'in' : {
            '$cond': [
                '$$myVariable1',
                { ... },
                { ... },
            ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is extremely unclear, and most notably for the absence of **completeness** since it does not state what the expected "variable" is meant to be through the usage of `$or`, nor what the `then` and `else` output of the `$cond` should be. Not to mention that since the "variable" is only being used in one place, it's a pretty *pointless* usage of `$let`. The other part is "Scala" is really just using the "Java" driver and hence has the same `Document` primitives. Might not have been the best choice for a bounty @Rohde Fischer.

Comment: Really in essence this is a ["please convert my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad), which as has been brought up many times before really should not be encouraged.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. Hopefully it helps someone.

```
val doc : Document = Document("{
     '$let': {
          'vars' : { 'myVariable1': { '$or': [...] } },
          'in' : { '$cond': ['$$myVariable1',{ ... },{ ... } ]
     }     

    }")

    var pipeline = mutable.Buffer[Bson]()
    pipeline += Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
      Projections.computed("myprojitem",doc)
    ))
```

Basically, every { name : expression } can be written as :

```
Document("name" -> expression)
```

Or

```
Document( "{name : expression}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$let` is used to bind variables together to a results obj. The syntax follows the rule:

```
{
  $let:
     {
       vars: { <var1>: <expression>},
       in: <expression>
     }
}
```

for mere details you should take a look at [$let (aggregation) definition from mongodb manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#definition)

Here is a text book example just to make more sense:

**Consider the following data:**

```
{ _id: 1, price: 10, tax: 0.50, applyDiscount: true }
{ _id: 2, price: 10, tax: 0.25, applyDiscount: false }
```

And imagine that we want to generate a result for the `finalTotal` in a way that:

[image]

Where Disc = 10% if `applyDiscount: true` and 0 otherwise.

So we need now to create the aggregation on the data to construct this equation. So we can get a results like:

```
{ _id: 1, finalTotal: 9.45 }
{ _id: 2, finalTotal: 10.25 }
```

We can do this by doing:

```
      $project: {
         finalTotal: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  total: { $add: [ '$price', '$tax' ] },
                  discounted: { $cond: { if: '$applyDiscount', then: (0.9, else: 1 } }
               },
               in: { $multiply: [ "$$total", "$$discounted" ] }
            }
         }
      }
```

**We can break this down:**

**Step 1.** adding price to tax together to a variable called `total`

```
total: { $add: [ '$price', '$tax' ] },
```

**Step 2.** transforming the condition in numbers (variable `discounted`)

```
discounted: { $cond: { if: '$applyDiscount', then: 0.9, else: 1 } }
```

**Step 3.** performing the operation `$multiply` operation between the constructed `$$total` and `$$discounted`

```
in: { $multiply: [ "$$total", "$$discounted" ] }
```